# symfony js rendered bottom of page but needed earlier

Tags: javascript, symfony

Using symfony, i render at the bottom of my page in base.html.twig a js library. Before that however I have a render function to render a template, and in there I require functionality from the library.

Is there a way to solve this cleanly?

Comment: your js is at bottom of page¿

Comment: Yes thats what I said, bottom of my base.html.twig file, below the body, usually I was taught thats what you should do with js?

Comment: and you need to set at head?¡

Comment: im guessing the only way is to put the js in the head of the html?

Comment: ahh, in some cases to optimize page load, it uses to put js at bottom. That tecnique is most used in wwwordpress

Answer (score 0):

Your render functionality have to be encapsulated into closure.

Please use this skeleton:

```
(function(){
    // put your JS code here
})();
```

It will allow to run code inside closure to run when document will be ready.

Comment: its a twig function: {{ render(controller("AppBundle:Home\\Filter:filter")) }}

Comment: So what's the problem? You do not need encapsulation around twig function.